# which Active Directory's attribute corresponds to STATUS_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

Does anyone knows which AD attribute makes or has realiton with the next error displayed in a laptop Windows 7 machine?

Account Logon  "Logon attempt 
Error Code:        0xC0000234

Note that this error implies a STATUS_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT error in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

To check if the account is locked out. You can check the account's msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed attribute. See if the ADS_UF_LOCKOUT (0x00000010) bit is set.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223393.aspx

Note that this is a constructed attribute.

To unlock an account, you can set the lockoutTime attribute to 0.
For example, in C#:

```
accountEntry.Properties["lockoutTime"].Value = 0;
accountEntry.CommitChanges();
```